# python3 unicode fails when lowercasing

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, unicode, lowercase

I'm facing a very strange issue with Python 3:

```
>>> a = "abcé"
>>> a
'abcé'
>>> print(a)
abcé
>>> print(a.lower())
abc�
```

I have no idea where this comes from, but it fails to lowercase unicode characters. Note that I'm not able to reproduce the bug everywhere, this is just on one of my computers that I get the following issue. Also, python2 on that same computer properly prints `abcé`.

Also, `a.upper()` is returning `ABCé` instead of `ABCÉ`, so it does not suffer the same issue than `lower`..

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, tag Python too.

Comment: Note that lowercasing is inherently an operation that always needs a language/locale. So I would never expect `lower` without any arguments to yield anything sensible, in any programming language.

Comment: Works for me in Python 3.4.

Comment: Works for me in Python 3.6. It returns ABCÉ after .upper()

Comment: can you do `import locale` and `locale.getlocale()` directly in the python shell and post the results?

Comment: Is it possible I have some wrong environment variable?

Comment: @hansaplast it gives me "('en_US', 'ISO8859-1')"

Comment: can you try `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')` and then do the `lower()` operation again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you observed is indeed very peculiar: the letter "é" being unaffected by Python's `str.upper()`, and turned into a replacement character by `str.lower()`.
It is also strange that this appears to depend on the environment, since the said `str` methods don't exhibit any localisation (even though this would arguably make sense sometimes, as in the case of the Turkish mapping of "i"→"İ" and "ı"→"I"), but always use Unicode's default case algorithm.

#### Possible explanation

The most likely explanation for this weird phenomenon is that Python doesn't "see" the same data as you.
As Hansaplast wrote in their answer, there's probably an encoding mismatch between the terminal and the Python interpreter.
One usually doesn't have to care about this, but when you use the interactive interpreter, the job of displaying typed and printed characters isn't actually performed by Python, but by the terminal [emulator], and this additional layer can be a source of problems sometimes.

So what exactly is going on?
I believe the following scenario can explain the observed behaviour:

- Your terminal is configured to use UTF-8. When you type "é", it will send the bytes `C3 A9` to Python. When it receives `C3 A9` from Python, it will display "é".
- Python, however, uses Latin-1, as you confirmed through the return value of `locale.getlocale()`. When it receives `C3 A9`, it decodes this to "Ã©", which is a common case of mojibake.
- UTF-8 and Latin-1 are both supersets of ASCII, so as long as you only use ASCII characters, this misconfiguration is not an issue. When you type "A", Python reads "A", and the same for output.

The really nasty thing about this misconfiguration is that it is only visible in certain circumstances.
Even non-ASCII characters might pass through unnoticed because of the symmetry of en-/decoding.
If Python simply echoes its input, ie. prints "Ã©", this will be de-mojibaked by the terminal into "é", so the mistake is hidden.
But when the individual characters are interpreted in some way – as with `str.upper()` and `lower()` –, unexpected things might occur.

In your case, `.upper()` has no effect, because "Ã" is upper-case already and "©" is caseless. That is why `'abcé'.upper()` results in `'ABCé'` on the screen.
But lowercasing produces "ã©", which Python encodes as `E3 A9`.
Since this is not a valid UTF-8 byte sequence, the terminal fails at interpreting it and shows a replacement character (�) instead.

#### Solutions

If this explanation is true, how do you fix the encoding misconfiguration?

- For interactive sessions, it probably makes sense that Python uses environment variables such as `LC_ALL` for setting the encoding of STDIN/STDOUT. Put a line like `export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8` in a start-up script for the shell that runs in your terminal, eg. *.bashrc*. Changing the locale from within Python has no effect because the STD-stream encoding is set on start-up and won't be updated when you call `locale.selocale()`.
- For scripts, you might not want to rely on environment variables.
  You can create a new `io.TextIOWrapper` around the binary stream underlying each standard channel:

  ```
  sys.stdin = open(sys.stdin.buffer.fileno(), encoding='utf8')
  sys.stdout = open(sys.stdout.buffer.fileno(), 'w', encoding='utf8')
  sys.stderr = open(sys.stderr.buffer.fileno(), 'w', encoding='utf8')
  ```

  (I don't recommend this solution for interactive sessions. Especially if you mistype something, you can get in a situation from where it's difficult to recover.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what happens here but it looks like some encoding issues between python and your terminal.

Best practice is anyway to keep everything in 'utf-8' so to ensure that you could either do `import locale` and `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')` from within python or do `export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8`.

I'm not 100% fluent on these encoding topics so maybe an encoding expert has a better answer/explanation but this should solve your case.

Comment: Interesting, using `setlocale` from python did not work, but the `export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8` in bash before opening python solved the issue!

Comment: I think the following is happening: @dhokas' terminal is configured to send and interpret everything in UTF-8, but Python uses Latin-1. So the terminal sends "é" as the bytes `C3 A9`, which Python sees as "Ã©". Since "Ã" is uppercase and "©" is caseless, `.upper()` returns the same byte sequence, which is interpreted and displayed by the terminal as "é". However, `.lower()` turns this into "ã©", which encodes as `E3 A9` in Latin-1. Since `E3 A9` is no valid UTF-8 sequence, the terminal cannot interpret it and displays a replacement character.

Comment: @lenz nice answer! do you care to put it into a separate answer, I think this should be the accepted solution, not mine

Comment: @hansaplast FWIW, I turned it into a (longish) answer.

Comment: @dhokas: you might want to choose lenz's excellent answer as accepted. His answer has a lot more information than mine and is also more correct as it shows why `setlocale()` didn't work